# Downloadable word lists?

Tags: dictionaries

What is the best downloadable US-English word list?
Similar to a dictionary without the definitions.

I've found https://github.com/en-wl/wordlist which is the source list for he English dictionary used by many open-source projects, however it doesn't attempt to be a complete list *(they avoid adding less common words since it can confuse auto-suggestions)*.

Comment: This type of question is usually better on Meta

Comment: No list can ever be complete. (If you do ever see a list that says it attempts to be complete, it is safe to disregard it as nonsense compiled by someone who obviously doesn't know the first thing about how languages work.) With that out of the way, you can either download the list of US words from the English Wiktionary, or go to OmegaWiki where they compile all the data from all the Wiktionaries, not just the English one. Then you can merge it with the list from GitHub.

Comment: And of course there's always COCA, but their list is only available for a hefty fee.

Comment: The question is also opinion based. I have several lists suitable for different purposes. The largest has 375,000 words, but it is not always the best list. For some purposes there are too many obscure entries.